# Is it possible to get result in multiple format type (csv, txt) using @query_attachment_filename in SQL Server using Database Mail?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @tab char(1) = CHAR(9), 
        @mysubject varchar(100)='Daily Transaction Count '+cast(FORMAT(getdate(),'MM/dd/yy') as varchar(100))

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    @profile_name = 'Email',  
    @recipients = 'email@gmail.com',  
    @copy_recipients = 'email@gmail.com',
    @body = 'Hi User',  
    @subject = @mysubject,
    @query = 'exec Testing..usp_SqlAgentDemoTable',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
    @query_attachment_filename = 'Daily Transaction Count.txt',
    @query_result_no_padding=1,
    @body_format ='HTML',
    @query_result_separator=@tab,
    @query_result_width =134
```

Is it possible to get result of a query in multiple format type like (csv, txt) using **@query_attachment_filename** in SQL Server Agent using Database Mail?

I'm able to get csv or txt format file attachment, but I'm unable to get both the type file format attachment in a single email.
Any help would be highly appreciated?

Comment: This above is clearly SQL Server, so why tag [tag:sqlite] too?

Comment: @Larnu Removed it!

Comment: As for what your asking, no, you can't control the format of the files; SQL Server defines that. If you want to control the file types you need to use a different solution. Perhaps, for example, SSRS.

Comment: @Larnu I'm new to this, That means we can able to send only any one file format type using EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail. Correct me If I'm wrong

Comment: That is exactly what I am saying, yes. Note that there is nothing in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to denote the formatting properties for the attachement.